# Loading LIDAR data to POSTGRES and use it with DJANGO

Tags: postgresql, lidar, references, geodjango, django

I have some project at the Faculty and I don't know from where to begin.
I have point cloud data (LIDAR data) and I need to make the website with that data on it and with functions for some sort of manipulation with that data, like some measurements, etc. I have to use the Postgres database and Django for that. These days I am learning Django, watching tutorials, etc.. And I didn't find anywhere a way to work with LIDAR data, so If someone can just help me with some guidelines.

To sum up, all that I said.

I must:

-use LIDAR data

-POSTGRES database

-DJANGO framework

-Publish LIDAR data to the site and add some options for manipulating with the data (like seeing profiles, measurements, etc)

Everything else is optional.

I imagine creating something like this: https://cesiumjs.org/Cesium/Build/Apps/Sandcastle/index.html?src=3D%20Tiles%20Feature%20Styling.html (right window - 3d model of this city), just with the LIDAR dataset.

Comment: I have the freedom to make website whatever I wanted to be, but conditions are to use LIDAR data which is given to me, POSTGRES database and DJANGO with RESTFUL API. That it my project at Faculty, I didn't choose it. I just need guidelines from people whose have experience in these topics. I didn't start doing anything concrete, I am watching tutorials and learning at the moment.

Comment: Thank you for that. Is it better now? 
I saw questions on this kind of sites where people ask for opinions from where to start and get some good advice, materials, etc. That is all I want for now. :/

Answer (score 1):

Here's an outline of how I suggest approaching this project.

1. Start by asking some questions. You can ask and answer them yourself, or poll your colleagues and potential users of the site.

   - Who will use this website?
   - What are their needs?
   - Will they use the website to...

     - Make measurements? If so, what kind of measurements?
     - View the data with a variety of basemaps, such as satellite photography from different years?
     - Navigate? If so, will they want routing/directions?
     - Select a feature and get information about it?
     - Select multiple features or an area on the map, and get aggregated statistics (eg, average rainfall in a selected area)?
     - Print maps? If so, will they want to:

       - draw on the map
       - add text annotations
       - include measurements, navigation info, or statistics on the printout
     - Etc.
2. Using the answers as a guide, create an outline of all the things you want the site to do.
3. Decide which features are must-haves, and which are wants. Figure out if your chosen software package can do all the must-haves. If not, find a software that can.
4. Learn how to implement those features. Search the web for tutorials, youtube videos, etc.
5. Work on implementing the features. Post questions on StackExchange when you get stuck.